# Is there a simple way to remove sublits

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list(rs_data) with sublists obtained from a Dataframe, and some rows from Dataframe contain multiple elements, like those:

```
print(rs_data)
rs1791690, rs1815739, rs2275998
rs6552828
rs1789891
rs1800849, rs2016520, rs2010963, rs4253778
rs1042713, rs1042714, rs4994, rs1801253
```

I want to obtain a list in which each element (rs….) is separated, something like this:

```
 {'rs1791690', 'rs1815739', 'rs227599', 'rs401681', 'rs2180062', 'rs9018'….}
```

How can I eliminate sublits or generate a new list without sublists, in which each element is unique.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a new list you could iterate over the old one and throw out the elements you don't like.

Something like this

```
for i in rs_data:
    if i in bad_values:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

If you just want to eliminate duplicates it would be the best to use a set
Like this

```
mynewset = set(rs_data)
```